# General TypeScript usage for modules / namespaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, node-modules, javascript-namespaces

I have a standard web page (not an app rendered with angular, react, vue, etc) that uses jQuery, and other libraries.

I want to integrate good practices with TypeScript.
What is the best way to do this?

My current idea is to have 3 files:

1. the index.d.ts (describes the types of my module)
2. the test.ts (the implementation of the types described in the index.d.ts)
3. the page.js (the file that uses the javascript defined in the test.js -- output from the test.ts)

I currently have these contents:

**index.d.ts**

```
// Type definitions for test 1.0.0
// Project: Test
// Definitions by: Author Name

/// <reference path="../../lib/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
declare namespace TestNS {
    export class TestClass {
        // Fields
        element: JQuery;
        value: string;

        constructor(element: JQuery, val: string);

        OnCreate();

        static AttachToJQuery(jq: JQueryStatic): void;
    }

    interface JQuery {
        TestClass(element: JQuery, val?: string): TestNS.TestClass;
    }

    interface JQueryStatic {
        TestClass(element: JQuery, val?: string): TestNS.TestClass;
    }
}
```

**Test.ts** (loaded 2nd, after jQuery)

```
/// <reference path="../../lib/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./index.d.ts" />

export namespace TestNS {
    export class TestClass {
        // Fields
        element: JQuery;
        value: string;

        constructor(element: JQuery, val: string) {
            this.element = element;
            this.value = val;
            this.OnCreate();
        }

        OnCreate() {
            this.element.data('test-value', this.value);
        }

        static AttachToJQuery(jq: JQueryStatic) {
            //no jQuery around
            if (!jq) {
                return false;
            }

            jq.fn.extend({
                TestNS: function(newVal) {
                    return this.each(function() {
                        var obj = jq(this);
                        new TestNS.TestClass(obj, newVal);

                    });
                }
            });
        }//attach to jquery method (to easily work with noconflict mode)
    }//test class
}
```

**page.js** (loaded last)

```
let newJquery:JQueryStatic = jQuery.noConflict();
TestNS.TestClass.AttachToJQuery(newJquery);

let testElems = newJquery(".testClass");
testElems.TestClass();
```

My goal is to have my code neatly organized into a namespace in typescript, as well as on the page (but doing so in typescript gives errors related to duplicate identifiers) as well as being modular and extensible. I understand that I should publish my types under the "node_modules/@types" directory, but I simply want them all encapsulated in this module for now.

I have tried using a module, and importing what is defined in the index.d.ts, but TypeScript says I cannot import this file, and that the module name cannot be found. I did learn that if I use a module, it should be accompanied with a loader, such as CommonJS, RequireJS or AMD, but I would prefer to avoid that for now (if it's not a horrible practice to do so, as I want to minimize the levels of complexity for now).

I've tried looking at other projects, but they all use a loader, which seems a bit overkill for this kind of script.

Is there a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make things work without a module loader, you will have to make a few changes. First of all it's worth mentioning that TypeScript supports 2 primary ways of modularizing code, namespaces and modules.

NOTE: A slightly confusing nuance here is that the keywords `namespace` and `module` can be used interchangebly and don't by themselves determine whether a thing is a module or a namespace.

1) modules (formerly called external modules) - these use typical import, export, and require semantics and require a module loader and preferably a bundler of some sort. For this pattern, each file is considered a module. Any file that contains any import or export statements will be considered an external module by the TypeScript compiler.

2) namespaces (formerly called internal modules) - this pattern supports namespaces that can span multiple files. This is the module type that you would need to use if you don't want to use a module loader. Usage of this pattern is becoming less common, but it is still an option if you want to use it for whatever reason. To use this type of modularization, you can't have any import or export statements in the file.

Here's the docs on `namespaces` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Assuming you want to go with your original plan, you will need to tweak a couple of things in your code.

1) As mentioned by @sbat, your `index.d.ts` is re-declaring your namespace and class types. This is likely causing duplicate definition errors. You can replace the entire contents with a simple override of the JQuery interface.

```
/** Extend the JQuery interface with custom method. */
declare interface JQuery {
    TestNS: () => TestNS.TestClass
}
```

2) Make sure you don't have any top level exports or imports. Specifically you will want to remove the `export` from your namespace in `test.ts`. This will make your module an `internal` one instead of an `external` one.

```
namespace TestNS {
    export class TestClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: if I remove the namespace and such from the index.d.ts file, then would I not get TypeScript support (it wouldn't know of the types for this namespace/objects)?

Comment: You are already telling the compiler your types in your test.ts file. The only type you are missing that I can tell is the JQuery extension which shouldn't be nested in your namespace.

Comment: So an index.d.ts file is basically not needed for namespaced code not in a module? (or an external module)

Comment: The need for an index.d.ts file isn't related to whether its a namespace or a module. It's related to whether your source code is written in TypeScript or not. Even if you used modules, you wouldn't want to duplicate your type definitions.

Comment: You typically use .d.ts files to tell the compiler about types it can't determine from source code. This would also be how you can tell consumers of your code what types it contains if you were to publish it as .js runtime code, but you don't want duplicate type definitions in the same source code that is being compiled.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. 

Coming from c++, I assumed d.ts files were like c++ files, and you declare ambient (interfaces, namespaces, etc, but just with types and method signatures). Then I assumed this would be in an implementation file that would "consume" the d.ts "header." 

Your explanation makes a lot of sense. I wish the documentation for typescript on index.d.ts files are more verbose about it's usage cases, and what it DOES to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to just try TypeScript in a simple project, I'd suggest you simplify things a bit:

- Remove index.d.ts. Definition files describe existing javascript code, so that TypeScript is aware of types in it. You don't have this situation in your project, there is no need to repeat type information you have already in your test.ts, you can safely remove this file.
- Just build your test.ts into test.js. Make sure your jquery .d.ts is located where it should be.
- Remove page.js, just code everything in test.ts for a test. Once you make it work, you can reorganize it.

However, if your goal is to have your code modular and extensible, the recommended approach is to indeed use modules:

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, modules are native part of the
>   language, and should be supported by all compliant engine
>   implementations. Thus, for new projects modules would be the
>   recommended code organization mechanism.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

To use modules in production environment in the browser you will need:

- Bundler. A tool that will call TypeScript to build your individual TS modules, and then combine the build output into single javascript file. You will then include this single file into your HTML. WebPack is probably the easiest to start: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/
- Package manager. A tool that installs and manages versions of the third-party modules. https://www.npmjs.com/

This is a big area to study, but I don't think it is an overkill. If your code is modular (even if it is just 2 modules), you need an infrastructure to bundle and load your modules one way or the other. There are several options with different benefits and trade-offs, but there is fundamentally no way around that.